# Как работать с xpath в postgresql?

Tags: sql, база-данных, xml, postgresql

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tutorial>
    <title>&quot;Заметки об XSL&quot;</title>
    <author>Леонов Игорь Васильевич</author>
</tutorial>
```

Есть файл xml, положил вот в таком виде его в таблицу

```
CREATE TABLE testmy
(
    id integer NOT NULL,
    "text" text,
    "xml" xml,
    CONSTRAINT pk_id PRIMARY KEY (id)
)

INSERT INTO testmy(id, "text", "xml")
VALUES (9, 'тут xml','и тут xml');
```

не получается применить xpath, честно говоря я совершенно не понимаю, как его применять, поэтому мой код наверно даже будет смешным

```
select t.* from
xpath_table('id','text','textmy','/tutorial/title|/tutorial/author','true')
as t(id int4, title text, author text);
```

пишет: " функция xpath_table не существует"

если вдруг есть хороший гайд как работать с xml в pgsql ( не документация ) то можно тоже его скинуть.

P.S. Как положить xml документ из папки, чтобы не вводить постоянно его самостоятельно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`xpath_table` - это функция расширения xml2. Расширения надо предварительно подключать:

```
CREATE EXTENSION xml2;
```

Comment: Обращаю внимание читателей, что это расширение помечено устаревшим. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/xml2.html А вот как этими стандартными SQL/XML средствами пользоваться - сходу не разобрался, так что более правильный ответ не напишу.